# How to increase/decrease brightness on my laptop Toshiba Tecra

Tags: brightness

If i want to adjust screen brightness on my laptop, brightness indicator it's working ok, but brightness it's remaining on maximum intensity.

It's possible to decrease screen brightness intensity ?

Comment: I-m solving this problem: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/